# Performing Activity after miss call

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and i want to build an App which sends message automatically after getting a miss call from a specific number.
I am well aware of the messaging in Android but dont know how to perform an Activity after a miss call.
Can anyone please help on this (if it is possible) and suggest where to learn new things about Android as a beginner.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a service that listens to call events and then make you app act accordingly, have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548416/Detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone-calls-on-And

Comment: thank you for your reply..but the link is for incoming call but how can i know that the receiving call is going to be miss call?...to be more precise is there a method for missed calls..so that I can perform a task for it?...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any particular state for miss calls but instead i used the three states i.e `CALL_STATE_RINGING`, `CALL_STATE_IDLE` and `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` like this :

```
    package com.example.misscall;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        int checkIt = 0;
        TelephonyManager tm;
        CallStateListener callStateListener = new CallStateListener();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }

        private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // called when someone is ringing to this phone

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Incoming: " + incomingNumber,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    checkIt = 1 ;
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK :
                    checkIt = 0;
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if(checkIt == 1)
                    //send message here
                    break;
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Since miss call will be when state first change from **IDLE** to **INCOMING_CALL** but when 
 it is picked up the state changes back to 0 (default).
 **but still there is problem** that when the user itself cancels the call then it will be counted as a miss call. Hope i  find a way out of it.